# Is it possible to automate FTP in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, data-transfer, ftp

I want to add an FTP command to my crontab to automatically download a file. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Unix wonders in Mac :)

Comment: you can use launchd instead of cron as it's the official apple supported scheduler now. Cron still works, but launchd is the way of the future :D

Comment: When did that change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easier way to do this is with [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget). For example:

```
Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro:ianc ian$ wget ftp://gnjilux.cc.fer.hr/welcome.msg
--2011-08-02 19:48:00--  ftp://gnjilux.cc.fer.hr/welcome.msg
           => `welcome.msg'
Resolving gnjilux.cc.fer.hr... 161.53.74.67
Connecting to gnjilux.cc.fer.hr|161.53.74.67|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD not needed.
==> SIZE welcome.msg ... 1462
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR welcome.msg ... done.
Length: 1462 (1.4K) (unauthoritative)

100% [======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 1,462       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2011-08-02 19:48:03 (63.4 MB/s) - `welcome.msg' saved [1462]
```

`wget` supports options to supply a user name (**--user**=*user*) and password (**--password**=*password*) if anonymous FTP access isn't available. And a **--quiet** mode so it's `cron`-friendly and doesn't fill up your local inbox without messages for successful downloads.

Comment: I used wget all last school year to download notes from my professor automatically just like this. Saved me from not having notes quite a few times since I never had to remember to get them.

Answer (score 4):

The BASH script below will work

```
#!/bin/bash

remotefile="/path/to/ftp/server/file.png"
hostname="ftp.server.net"
username="ftpuser"
password="ftppass"
ftp -in $hostname<<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password

binary
get $remotefile $HOME/temp/file.png
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use curl which is available under Mac OSX already and can (for non-anonymous ftp) use logins stored in .netrc (so the password doesn't show up in a ps listing)

Plain vanilla anonymous ftp

```
curl ftp://your.server.name/path/to/file.tar.gz > ~you/Downloads/file.tar.gz
```

Using .netrc

```
curl --netrc ftp://your.server.name/path/to/file.tar.gz > ~you/Downloads/file.tar.gz
```

Specify user/password directly (visible in ps afterwards)

```
curl --user "user:password" ftp://your.server.name/path/to/file.tar.gz > ~you/Downloads/file.tar.gz
```